# IE6 ShowModalDialog reuses the opened window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, modal-dialog

As my current project demands: I'm developing an ASP.net 3.0 website with Internet Explorer 6.0 SP1.

My problem is when I execute a javascript `window.showModalDialog()` from two separated browers they uses the same opened modal, I need to open a new modal for each browser.

Why is that?, Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the target of the showModalDialog call to "_blank" or "_new" (I forget which) - otherwise it will reuse an open browser instance.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for but I don't have an anchor (link) to open it, so how can I set the target?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I changed it to a window.open, so I added the target=_new and everything is working now.

Comment: Glad something worked. I tried googling for how to do that with showModalDialog, but I couldn't find any good code samples. And I used to use this all the time!